# Sharepoint SPUserField

Tags: sharepoint, moss, spuserfield

Is it possible to use the SPUserField in a custom aspx page without the SPUserField being bound to a field (it always asks for FieldName).
I basically have a custom page which ultimately creates a list item, i want the user to be able to pick another user from the standard Sharepoint control...

??

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can use [`PeopleEditor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.peopleeditor.aspx) control from `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` namespace. For instance, in one of my pages:

```
 <wssawc:PeopleEditor 
     AllowEmpty="false" id="allReviewers" runat="server"
     SelectionSet="User" width='500'/>
```